# AdWordsApp not available in Apps Script code editor - ScriptyApp Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

I've created a script in a spreadsheet that export an AdWords report to the spreadsheet.

```
function Export(ss, Ads180, Ads14){
     var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyyMMdd");
     var SixMonths = Utilities.formatDate(subDays(new Date(),180), "GMT", "yyyyMMdd");
     var TwoWeeks = Utilities.formatDate(subDays(new Date(),14), "GMT", "yyyyMMdd");
     var report = AdWordsApp.report(
       "SELECT AdGroupName,Headline, Description1, Description2, HeadlinePart1, HeadlinePart2, Description, Impressions, Ctr, Conversions, Id" +
           " FROM AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" +
           " WHERE Status='ENABLED' AND CampaignName="+campaignName+
           " DURING "+SixMonths+","+newDate+"");
     report.exportToSheet(Ads180);
     report.exportToSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Summary'));


      report = AdWordsApp.report(
       "SELECT AdGroupName,Headline, Description1, Description2, HeadlinePart1, HeadlinePart2, Description, Impressions, Ctr, Conversions, Id" +
           " FROM AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" +
           " WHERE Status='ENABLED' AND CampaignName="+campaignName+
           " DURING "+TwoWeeks+","+newDate+"");


     report.exportToSheet(Ads14);  

    }
```

I got a problem when I got the following error:

> ReferenceError: "AdWordsApp" is not defined

So I asked the AdWords Scripts Forum and they suggested to use the [AdWordsApp Library](https://script.google.com/a/macros/google.com/library/versions/d/12qYtxFp9Rzt6KIn9BkgXLAQpjyLCeA72VwA9xG_jjtK-7aIljCrPHvZs).
I used it, but now I get this strange error:

> ReferenceError: "ScriptyApp" is not defined
>   [The AdWordsApp Library and the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOQEd.jpg)
>   I don't know what to do next, could you please advise?

Thanks,
Maor

Comment: Are you going into the script editor through your AddWords account?  Do you have an AddWords account?

Comment: I'm going to the script editor in the Spreadsheet.
And yes, I have AdWords Acount (not mcc)

Comment: It looks like the AdWordsApp service is not available through the regular Apps Script code editor.  I can't find anything to enable AdWords in the regular Apps Script code editor.  I think you need to log in to AdWords, and then open their script editor while being logged into your account page.

Comment: I want to create a "Menu" in a spreadsheet, so I could enter manualy the capmpaign name, I can't do it through the AdWords script editor.
I try to use `Browser.inputBox()` in the AdWords script editor, and I get error **ReferenceError: "Browser" is not defined**

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge ScriptyApp, on which AdWordsApp depends, is not available in Apps Script. You need to use AdWords Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it seems like unfortunately Google excluded the use of ScriptyApp. Which was the base for the AdwordsApp to work on the Apps Script.